# SQL LIKE convert to SQL CONTAINS

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-like, contains

What is the right syntax for converting a SQL Like to Contains in the following fragment statement:

WHERE ReferenceNo LIKE '%' + @SearchString+ '%'

I have converted it to:

WHERE ReferenceNo CONTAINS(VendorName, @SearchString)

VendorName is in the SELECT statement.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: since VendorName is not in the WHERE version, what are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were just converting the WHERE statement you showed, it would be

```
WHERE CONTAINS(ReferenceNo, @SearchString)
```

Comment: i have set @SearchString = 'ON' just for testing, and checked if it returns the columns when the VendorName = 'ONE'. but with this query, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: if you're searching the VerndorName column, then replace ReferenceNo in my example with VendorName. It was not clear in your question which column you wanted to search against.

Comment: ya, i get what you mean here. VendorName is the column im searching against. im wondering why the CONTAINS function does not work for a pattern search (LIKE '%' + @SearchString+ '%'). or if there is a way for pattern search in CONTAINS, how is it constructed? :)

Comment: WHERE CONTAINS(VendorName, 'Acme') should return rows containing the string 'Acme' within the row's VendorName column (acts like LIKE '%Acme%'). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx for details and examples.

Comment: that query only returns records when the string is either at the beginning or at the end of the column value. 

example:

record1 ["ONE"]
record2 ["TWO"]
record3 ["ONE and TWO"]

when @SearchString = 'one' or when @SearchString = 'two', it returns two records but when @SearchString = 'and', no record is returned.

Comment: CONTAINS is doing full text search. It is like "LIKE", but not exactly the same. For instance, from the documentation I referenced above "Noise words (such as a, and, or the) in full-text indexed columns are not stored in the full-text index." You should read the docs about CONTAINS and full text indexing to see if CONTAINS is really what you want. You might also want to look at FREETEXT(columnName, searchString).